# Is reporting the sample size useful?

Tags: sample-size, reporting

I was browsing Reddit (r/science) and noticed that most submissions put the sample size in the headline, e.g. N=100. The same goes for many news sites. Is this information actually useful on its own?

I think what I actually want to know is the type I and II error rates. But Type I error is predetermined and unaffected by sample size AFAIK, and while the type II error rate does depend on sample size, it also depends on several other factors, so it would be more useful to directly report the Type II error rate or statistical power.

So my question is: does sample size, taken on its own, actually tell you anything about the quality of a study?

Comment: Yes; it can be useful. An old joke runs: 1/3 of the rats did this, 1/3 did that, and the other rat ran away. In rat studies, a sample size of 3 doesn't impress. Naturally, everything also depends on the field, how the sample was collected, and many, many other aspects of a study, but sample size itself can be informative about  a study. Contrariwise, some Nobel   Prizes (at least one I can think of, so my sample is really just 1) have been based on datasets that would fit on one sheet of paper.

Comment: It's likely that you have heard of many studies or reports that so many percent of people do or think this or that. The first two questions should be what sample size? how was the sample selected? (I don't mind if you regard the second question as more important, as it is.) So, this kind of example underlines that knowing the sample size is desirable.

Comment: No answers to date, and no other comments, but some people liked my comments, so some answer may be better than none.

Answer (score 3):

Yes; it can be useful. An old joke runs: 1/3 of the rats did this, 1/3 did that, and the other rat ran away. In rat studies, a sample size of 3 doesn't impress. Naturally, everything also depends on the field, how the sample was collected, and many, many other aspects of a study, but sample size itself can be informative about a study. Contrariwise, some Nobel Prizes (at least one I can think of, so my sample is really just 1) have been based on datasets that would fit on one sheet of paper.

It's likely that you have heard of many studies or reports that so many percent of people do or think this or that. The first two questions should be what sample size? how was the sample selected? (I don't mind if you regard the second question as more important, as it is.) So, this kind of example underlines that knowing the sample size is desirable.